# Comparing Generic Values

Tags: c#, sorting, generics

So i wanted to make a generic method that makes you an array with a specific length that you insert into and it sorts it at the same time.
so i was transfering it from int to generic T and i stumbled into a problem while trying to compare 2 variables of T. 
this is the code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
class Program
{
    public static T[] insertWhileSorting<T>(int x)
    {
        T[] arr = new T[x];
        for (int i = 0, k; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            T value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(), typeof(T));

            for (k = i; k > 0 && value.CompareTo(arr[k - 1]) < 0; --k) arr[k] = arr[k - 1];

            arr[k] = value;
        }
        return arr;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = insertWhileSorting<int>(5);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", arr));
    }
  }
}
```

and yes i know(i think)that simply inserting the values into an array and then sorting it is better but i'm doing it for an assignment

Comment: And what *is* the problem you´re stumbling into?

Comment: You either need to add a constraint to make sure `T` implements `IComparable<T>` or pass in a `IComparer<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to assert that the type `T` as implemented `IComparable<T>`. Using the [where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) key word you can restrict the type `T` with a condition that `T` has to implement `IComparable<T>`:

```
 public static T[] insertWhileSorting<T>(int x) where T: IComparable<T>
```

[IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) demands that the class in question implements the method `CompareTo`. Now the compiler should stop complaining that

> "T" does not contain a definition for "CompareTo" and cannot find an extension method "CompareTo"

EDIT:

this line can get you easily into trouble:

```
T value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(), typeof(T));
```

because the user can type simply a string like `"break"` which would result in an `FormatException` if you initially called it  like this:

```
int [] adda = insertWhileSorting<int>(5);
```

You can put this whole conversion and sorting routine into a `try` `catch` clause and give a warning when it crashes:

```
for (int i = 0, k; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        T value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(), typeof(T));

        for (k = i; k > 0 && value.CompareTo(arr[k - 1]) < 0; --k) arr[k] = arr[k - 1];

        arr[k] = value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That stuff was not convertible!");
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Better would be ICompareable<T>

Comment: @SuperMinefudge no problem.

Comment: @MongZhu While your here is there a way to make this statement:

int[] arr = insertWhileSorting<int>(5);
to be less of a pain to change for example something like this
var[] arr = insertWhileSorting<int>(5);
but that doesnot work.
what i mean is changing a single variable name to change the array type

Comment: @SuperMinefudge Sure, omit  the "[]" `var arr = insertWhileSorting<int>(5);`

Comment: @CSharpie oh so var isng just int atring and char its also int[] string[] and so on. Thanks extremly usful!